# Javac Compilation Encoding Issue

Tags: java, javac

Recently, we were migrating java build jobs from serverA to serverB, the java source code (which contains Chinese characters) compiles nicely on the original serverA with Ant (<javac encoding="GBK" ...>), but, when we checked out the same code to the new serverB and run the same Ant scripts, there occurred encoding errors as "unmappable character for encoding GBK". (The JDK version is the same).

We have no idea why the same source code with same Ant encoding parameter can have different compilation result.

Are there any settings that can potentially cause this issue, OS settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same source code? Do a file compare for the same file on the two servers. The character encoding may have messed something up when checking out to serverB.

Comment: @TedHopp I think you mean checking out from the same repository actually can get different file encodings due to potential corruptions.
I compared the error files from serverA and serverB with Beyond Compare, they seems to be the same.

Comment: Very strange... I would check `JAVA_HOME` and `javac -version` to make sure that a correct java is being used.

Comment: @PavelHoral Yes, java/javac -version both get the correct version

Comment: @foolhunger Are you able to verify that the problematic character is really valid GBK?

Comment: @PavelHoral The fact is, those characters are not valid GBK, and removing them can resolve the problem.
I don't understand why the original build job on serverA can compile, the code has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigates

1. the java files do have GBK encoding issues.
2. On serverB, the Ant build script has javac parameters **source=1.6 target=1.6**, while serverA don't.

After removing these 2 parameters on the <javac> task from serverB, the complication succeed.

We still don't understand the exact reason for that, but at least problem solved for now.

If you have any clue why this happened, please leave comments below.

Thanks